# How to convert from newsoap to xml using simplexelement,simple_to_string

Tags: magento, token

error_reporting(0);

session_start();

$link=$_POST['Host'];

$_SESSION['Host']=$link;

$client = new SoapClient("http://".$link."/api/soap/?wsdl");

```
                                     /*api credentials*/    
                                                           $apiuser=$_POST['User'];



                                                           $_SESSION['User']=$apiuser;




                                                           $apikey =$_POST['Key'];
                                                           $_SESSION['Key']=$apikey;

                                      /*Action to be made */

    $action =$_POST['Catalog']; 



    $_SESSION['Catalog']=$action;



                                        /*Error trapping if in case number will be input*/

                                            if(ctype_alpha(!$action))



                                                          {

                                                                    die('Incorrect format');
```

}

else

{

```
                                         $sess_id= $client->login($apiuser, $apikey);
```

/*api login*/

```
 echo"Total Active list Product:".(count($client->call($sess_id, $action)));
```

echo"

```
";
```

print_r($result=$client->call($sess_id,$action));

echo"";

}

?>

Array

(

[0] => Array

```
    (

        [product_id] => 1


        [sku] => ROx12345

        [name] => acer netbook

        [set] => 4

        [type] => simple

        [category_ids] => Array

            (

            )

        [website_ids] => Array

            (
                [0] => 1
            )


    )

[1] => Array

    (
        [product_id] => 2

        [sku] => Cats1234

        [name] => starbucks mug

        [set] => 4

        [type] => simple

        [category_ids] => Array
            (

            )

        [website_ids] => Array
            (

                [0] => 1

            )

    )

[2] => Array

    (

        [product_id] => 3


        [sku] => samsung2141


        [name] => samsung 3110


        [set] => 4


        [type] => grouped


        [category_ids] => Array

            (

            )

        [website_ids] => Array

            (

                [0] => 1
            )


    )
```

Comment: Please format and clean up your code to be more readable. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189

Comment: and use english to actually formulate a question, describe what your goal is, what you've done and what problem do you face

Comment: print_r($result=$client->call($sess_id,$action));how can i use this to convert in xml im new in new soap..but i use print_r to trace the value of the $result and that was the output stated above..the output is array and designated value